# Count values based on dates in another column in excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, formula

I have a list of values in a column and list of dates in another

[image]

I am trying to get the counts of values for different period of dates

What would be the ideal way to approach this

Comment: Probably COUNTIF or COUNTIFS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems incorrect -> the count "Moved between April and May" should be 0.
You need a COUNTIFS() function.

In your example use in cell B18:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A10;">="&DATE(2022;4;1);A2:A10;"<"&DATE(2022;5;1);B2:B10;"Moved")
```

In cell B20:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A10;">="&DATE(2022;2;1);A2:A10;"<"&DATE(2022;3;1);B2:B10;"Deleted")
```

I would put the criteria for the Countifs in separate cells so you can reference them. That is more flexible.